# VBA set print job using different pages from 2 worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

This has me stumped and cannot find anything close to a solution, any help appreciated.

Example - I have a workbook with multiple worksheets A to H. Each worksheet has identical page setup (ranges) on two pages with each page setup not connected to the other (blank rows in between pages). All worksheets are protected.

The task - I want to place a macro button on Worksheet D that will print page 2 of Worksheet C and Page 1 of worksheet D in one print job. The idea being that with the printer set to duplex I have the two pages printed either side of one sheet of paper.
I have seen some solutions requiring conversion to pdf first but would rather not if I can avoid it.

Is anyone up to the challenge?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

here ya go:

```
Sub Macro5()

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$D$47"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$48:$D$94"
    ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=1, To:=2, Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
End Sub
```

That is generic "Recorded Macro" Code. But its the basis for what you want. YOU WILL HAVE TO MODIFY SLIGHLTY to work with your setup.

Basically what you would do, is you'd set the print areas for the sheets you want to print. so where it says `ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$D$47"` thats page 1 on that sheet in my excel book. then: `ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$48:$D$94"` is page 2 in a different sheet. then you have to move those 2 sheets to be first and second (or it wont work). the line `ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=1, To:=2, Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False` prints the entire workbook, but, it only prints from pages 1 to 2. so basically, I set my print areas for 2 different sheets to be 1 page each in both sheets. so when printing those sheets, it'll only print the print area. then those 2 sheets are 1st and 2nd, so when printing pages 1 to 2, it will just print the 1 page from both sheets. if you have the printer set to 2 sided, it'll print on both sides of 1 page.

to dynamically set print area, you could use a loop to process rows, and if they are not blank, add them to the print area. an example of how to have multiple print areas:
`ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$D$14,$A$19:$D$`

and you'll need to use the cells address unfortunately like the above. so If i started out wigth the one print range and wanted to add another i could do:

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$D$14"
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea & "$A$19:$D$"
```

so adapt that with a loop and it shouild get you closer.

Comment: I have tried similar but what I forgot to mention is that the actual workbook for this macro is over 80 + worksheets the required pages to print are the last 60 or so and all worksheets have been page setup but the first 20 worksheets vary in page numbers. I think the ActiveWorkBook.print would work but the VBA code would have to determine which workbook page number is from the previous sheet and then the subsequent page number would be from the ActiveSheet.

Comment: is there just one page on each sheet needing to be printed?

Comment: basically there is no way to dynamically set the print areas. you cant define which pages in which sheets to print by using page number unless there is only 1 worksheet. if theres one worksheet you just select pages 1 - whatever or 5 - 7 etc... but with multiple sheets obviously that doesnt work. and how many columns / rows fit on a page differ between sheets based on column titles / data etc.. so you'll have to just use page setup and select appropriate print areas on the pages.

Comment: if you set the print area on every page, then printing entire workbook will work because itll just print the particular print area for each sheet.